# A fresh install of babun and clang will not work

Tags: c++, cygwin, clang, babun

I just spent the past 4 and a half hours trying to fix this, so please excuse me if i'm being a bit testy.

For a clean environment I just re-installed babun to try to get clang working.
The commands I executed were

```
pact install clang
clang -v
```

but there is no output. neither for clang++. This is a documented bug [here](https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/203) but it was reported as fixed over a year ago. I come here in desperation if anyone knows of a fix.

For the record, the bug was "fixed" in version 1.1.0

```
{ ~ }  » clang                                                                              ~ 127
{ ~ }  » babun --version                                                                    ~ 127
babun version 1.2.0
Created and maintained by Tom Bujok (@tombujok)
Copyright (c) 2014-2015.
```

Comment: And trying g++ or gcc throws an [error](http://www.snorflake.com/u/biae.txt)